# Find the largest values of each Cell among n pandas DataFrame's

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

'N' number of similar pandas DataFrames are available with different values.

Form **one DataFrame from 'N' DataFrames** such that it contains the largest values in each cell.

```
A= pd.DataFrame({"pt":[0.15,0.25,0.5,0.75,1], "A1": [2,8,45,15,64], "A2":[10,4,55,17,10], "A3": [-1,9,4,24,77] })
B= pd.DataFrame({"pt":[0.15,0.25,0.5,0.75,1], "A1": [7,11,35,12,47], "A2":[-55,45,78,3,0], "A3": [55,88,23,1,3] })
C= pd.DataFrame({"pt":[0.15,0.25,0.5,0.75,1], "A1": [5,45,15,17,37], "A2":[107,5,54,30,89], "A3": [-102,51,11,10,30] })
C= ....
D= ....
```

Fastest way to get **ONE DataFrame with largest value in each cell**.

**Is there any other method without iterating through every DataFrame in loops?**

Comment: Can you provide the exact expected output (only considering A/B/C) for clarity?

Answer (score 0):

Combine [`concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) and [`groupby.max`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.max.html) with `pt` as grouper:

```
out = pd.concat([A, B, C]).groupby('pt', as_index=False).max()
```

*NB. if the DataFrames are fully aligned, you can also use `groupby(level=0)`.*

Output:

```
     pt  A1   A2  A3
0  0.15   7  107  55
1  0.25  45   45  88
2  0.50  45   78  23
3  0.75  17   30  24
4  1.00  64   89  77
```